# my app indicated a memory leak having trouble with componentWillmount()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, components

Hello I am having trouble with component will mount and Unmount and I am not sure if that is just me signing in and out with different accounts to test the firebase name display but I am not entirely sure I keep getting this message after signing in and out about 3 times

`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

here is my code with the componentWillMount and UnMount

```
    _isMounted = false;

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          authenticated: false,
          user: null ,
          loading: true
        }
      }
        componentWillMount() {
          this._isMounted = true;

          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

            if (user) {
                this.setState({
                  authenticated: true,
                  currentUser: user,
                  loading: false
                });
            } else {
              this.setState({
                authenticated: false,
                currentUser: null,
                loading: false
              });
            }
          });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
          this._isMounted = false;
        }
```

and I keep getting the error and I am wondering Why I think it has something to do with me signing in multiple times but I don't want that error to show up no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

Even though guys are correct above I'd advise you to check:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

since that isMounted you are doing there is antipattern and is not recommended.

Proper way would be to use that `makeCancelable` function from the article and make your setState cancelable promises i.e.

```
this.cancelablePromise = makeCancelable(
  new Promise(r => this.setState({
              authenticated: true,
              currentUser: user,
              loading: false
            }))
);
```

After you create those promises just do something like:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.cancelablePromise.cancel();
}
```

Keep in mind, all above is just for your guidance and may require some adjusting but will solve problem if you do it correctly.

Comment: So this is a separate function from the rest this is not to be implemented in any other function ?

Comment: You will need to copy that makeCancelable function from the article anywhere. I'd suggest put it outside and import here and reuse it later on another place if you have same issue. For cancelablePromise you will need to put that where your firebase call is. You can probably pass entire thing (firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged) to makeCancelable.and assign it to variable on which you will call cancel - same as above. Just try to play around with it until you make it, shouldn't be too hard if you read the article and what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

First `componentWillMount` has been deprecated, you should just do that stuff on `componentDidMount`, cos that's when has ACTUALLY mounted.

Secondly, in your firebase callback you'll want to check if the component is mounted before trying to do `setState`. You've already made the flag with your `this._isMounted` property, but you don't actually check it. It should be

```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      if (this._isMounted){
         // do setState stuff with user here
      }
```

Comment: would i do `if (this._isMounted){}` over the whole `if(user){} ?`

Comment: Yes, so like `if (this.isMounted){ if (user) { //do setState stuff } }`

Comment: It runs smoothly but for some reason When I sign in with a different account it gives me the error is it because Firebase.auth() is a async function

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `onAuthStateChanged` call is async. So it's possible for the following to happen:

1. Your component gets unmounted
2. The `auth()` callback happens
3. Still tries to run the `setState` code, which by now is an unmounted component.

What you can do is add a check for your flag `this._isMounted` before calling `setState`

Comment: Since it is async would that mean that Me signing in and out would be a bad thing is that making the component unmounted and that is why it is giving me back the error message